# How is this RS485 Module Working?

Tags: uart, rs485

I am planning to use this UART-to-RS485 module :- 
http://www.elecrow.com/uart-ttl-to-rs485-twoway-converter-p-1545.html.
This module is bidirectional and uses a single pair of differential signal to transmit/receive data. My question is how is the chip deciding whether it has to transmit data from TXD to A+ B- or from A+ B- to RXD?. Shouldn't there be 2 pair of differential signals, one pair for TX and the other pair for RX? What is happening in this module??

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at how rs485 works? Did you come across the term "half duplex" during your research?

Comment: @PlasmaHH - I think you may be missing the point i.e. how does the chip automatically change data direction.

Comment: @dim: interesting, I only ever worked with three wire rs458 (D+, D-, GND) in a bus setup where you have to deal with access collisions anyways.

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you tell which RS485 transceiver that's mounted on the board.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

More than likely it switches into transmit mode when TXD becomes active and a diode and capacitor "latch" that first transmit edge and hold that voltage "active" for longer than at least one byte.

I see a little surface mount diode on the PCB (D1) and quite possibly this is what I'm referring to. I have seen this trick done before and the only disadvantage is that when the TX session ends there might be a few milliseconds to wait before the RX direction is restored (due to the capacitor discharging).

I found this on the web as a partial circuit: -

[image]

When receiving, TX0 is active high thus forcing a low on DE (as expected). When TX0 goes low it rapidly discharges C0 and sets up the direction port for transmitting. When transmitting and TX data changes state, C0 remains largely discharged although ultimately R3 will slowly (relatively speaking) re-charge it but not until some time after the last transmit byte has been sent. Values shown i.e. 22k and 1000pF are dependent on baud rate.

Comment: sir could you please draw the circuit

Comment: @RishiSharma -You have the module. Why don't you inspect the circuit, get data sheets for the parts and draw your own schematic. It is rather outlandish that you could even expect Andy to do it then even have the gall to ask in the first place.

Comment: @MichaelKaras well I don't have the module actually........I was thinking of replicating it on a pcb I am designing.....I just couldn't figure out the working of this module. Plus there is no datasheet or anything that I could find on the website.

Comment: @RishiSharma - Well your question did say "I am using this RS485...".

Comment: @Andy aka  I have the module with me but now I cannot identify the second chip. Could you or anyone else please suggest what that ic could be

Comment: It might be a hex inverter, a quad nand gate or a quad or gate.

Comment: I tried this circuit but the problem is when I send data at 9600 baud rate. if sending string below 30 character is working fine but more than 30 characters. I received weird characters. Do you have any suggestion for accept range 9600 to 115200 baud rate for 200 characters any help please ?

Comment: @Minhm ask a formal question and provide a schematic.

Answer (score 6):

I reverse engineered the exact board pictured in the asker's post. The resistor and capacitor values are not what are there on the board - I selected them for my own circuit. However the schematics is almost accurate - "almost" because I have added a 120 ohms impedance matching resistor and capacitors on the A+, B- lines.

[image: UART to RS485 Schematics]

Comment: Are you sure (in your schematic) that the "GND" net for the RS-485 side of the circuit is the same "GND" net for the digital side? I found no such connection within an identical module. Did you add it?

Comment: @DineshT your solution not working in my case. I reverse engineering the blue board again. Here is my solution: [USB/UART - RS-485 Converter](https://oshwlab.com/Draxter/rs485v2)

Answer (score 1):

Working with DineshT's circuit as a starting point, I had an EE friend of mine work from that circuit as well as a sample of one of these boards. Our boards were purchased from Drok, who is a reseller on Amazon. The primary reason for reverse engineering the boards was to ensure they were RoHS compliant. If that is not important, the Drok boards work perfectly fine. The Drok boards had atypical spacing between the pins, which for compatibility, we kept. As noted elsewhere, ground on the right side is not connect to EARTH on the right side. There is an LDO voltage regulator that allows one of these to work with 5V and 3.3V Arduino and other boards. The RS-485 chip we used is nicely speced.

[image: SCHEMATIC]

[image: DROK vs DIY]